# if statement file_get_html Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, dom, if-statement

Search around google, php docs and ofc stack overflow and could not find something to work with, I need some help with some code I need to write a `if` statement for my function `file_get_html` that's obviously called using `Simple HTML DOM Parser`

I need it to return with a simple echo like `Hello World` if it only appears as `http://sweetvideos.net` but it will output as `$element->content` as my current script does for `og:image` I gave it a few attempts myself for hours and keep returning with this..

`file_get_contents(http://sweetvideos.net): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND`

**Can anyone help me?**

my code:

```
include('include/simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "?video=12c11210";
$html = file_get_html('http://sweetvideos.net' . $url);

if ($html->find('meta[property=og:image]')) {
  foreach ($html->find('meta[property=og:image]') as $element) {
    $img[] = $element->attr['content'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you?

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with curling but since my current code works I just need help with an extension of that.

Comment: can you please share simple_html_dom.php?

Comment: I ran your code and it returning complete dom object. What exactly your issue is?

Comment: I wish to add a `if` for file_get_html so that `if` it comes up with the text string http://sweetvideos.net only and not `http://sweetvideos.net/?video=blahblah` echo something like "The video did not load" I'm still new to php but I can't figure this out.

Comment: I found this article, but I don't understand it very well http://www.akshitsethi.me/parsing-web-pages-in-php/